# Python: how to replace NaN with conditions in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a dataframe `df1` that corresponds to the egelist of `nodes` in a network and `value` of the nodes themself like the following:

```
df
    node_i    node_j    value_i   value_j
0    3         4          89         33
1    3         2          89         NaN
2    3         5          89         69
3    0         2          45         NaN
4    0         3          45         89
5    1         2          109        NaN
6    1         8          109        NaN
```

I want to add a column `w` that correspond to the `value_j` if there is the value. If `value_j` is `NaN` I would like to set `w` as the average of the values of the adjacent nodes of `i`. In the case that `node_i` has only adjacent nodes with `NaN` values set `w=1`.

so the final dataframe should be like the foolowing:

```
df
    node_i    node_j    value_i   value_j      w
0    3         4          89         33       33
1    3         2          89         NaN      51      # average of adjacent nodes
2    3         5          89         69       69
3    0         2          45         NaN      89      # average of adjacent nodes
4    0         3          45         89       89
5    1         2          109        NaN       1      # 1
6    1         8          109        NaN       1      # 1
```

I am doing a loop like the following but I would like to use `apply`:

```
nodes = pd.unique(df['node_i'])
df['w'] = 0
for i in nodes:
    tmp = df[df['node_i'] == i]
    avg_w = np.mean(tmp['value_j'])
    if np.isnan(avg_w):
          df['w'][idx] = 1
    else:
          tmp.ix[tmp.value_j.isnull(), 'value_j'] = avg_w ## replace NaN with values
          df['w'][idx] = tmp['value_j'][idx]
```

Comment: What would be the adjacent nodes in row 1 and row 3?

Comment: @sobek The adjacent node of `node_i` in row 1 is `df['node_j'][1] = 2` while the adjacent node of `node_i` in row 3 is `df['node_j'][3] = 2`

Comment: It is unclear what you mean with *average values of the adjacent nodes*.

Comment: @sobek they are the adjecent nodes of `node_i`. For instance the adjacent nodes of `node_i=3` are `[4,2,5]`,  the adjacent nodes for `node_i=0` are `[2,3]` and the adjacent nodes for `node_i=1` are `[2,8]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `groupby` to do this:

```
fill_value = df.groupby("node_i")["value_j"].mean().fillna(1.0)
df["w"] = fill_value.reindex(df["node_i"]).values
df["w"][df["value_j"].notnull()] = df["value_j"][df["value_j"].notnull()]
```

Answer (score 4):

I Think you need `fillna` using once `ffill` and `bfill` and take average of it then `fillna` with `1` as:

```
df['w'] = ((df['value_j'].fillna(method='ffill')+df['value_j'].fillna(method='bfill'))/2).fillna(1).astype(int)

df
    node_i  node_j  value_i value_j w
0   3       4       89      33.0    33
1   3       2       89      NaN     51
2   3       5       89      69.0    69
3   0       2       45      NaN     79
4   0       3       45      89.0    89
5   1       2       109     NaN     1
6   1       8       109     NaN     1
```

**Updated Answer:**

You can use `groupby` and `transform` to find `mean` then `fillna` with `1` and use `np.where` to fill the values of `w` as:

```
values = df.groupby('node_i')['value_j'].transform('mean').fillna(1)
df['w'] = np.where(df['value_j'].notnull(),df['value_j'],values).astype(int)

df

    node_i  node_j  value_i value_j w
0   3       4       89      33.0    33
1   3       2       89      NaN     51
2   3       5       89      69.0    69
3   0       2       45      NaN     89
4   0       3       45      89.0    89
5   1       2       109     NaN     1
6   1       8       109     NaN     1
```

Comment: a question: how do you check the correspondence with `node_i`?

Comment: This logic definitely doesn't work in general. If `node_i = 3` had 3 non-null values and one NaN value, you'd be completely ignoring one of the consecutive non-null values, and still only averaging the two `NaN` adjacent values.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that by 'adjacent nodes' of `i`, you ultimately want the average of the `value_j`'s across all the rows of the same `i`.

In which case, we can use a `groupby` `transform` with `fillna`:

```
means = df.groupby('i')['value_j'].transform(np.mean)
# this gives the correct values for w in the rows where value_j is null,
# except when all the adjacent nodes have null value_j  (in which case it's still null)
filled_means = means.fillna(1)
# this corrects the last problem
df['w'] = df['value_j'].fillna(filled_means)
# this copies value_j, and fills the null rows with the corresponding rows from filled_means
# and assigns it to the column 'w'
```

Answer (score 0):

`apply` might not be the quickest solution but since it is your request, you can proceed like this:

```
def nan_with_cond(row):
    if ~np.isnan(row['value_j']) : return row['value_j']
    else: return df.loc[df['node_i'] == row['node_i'], 'value_j'].mean()

df['w'] = df.apply(nan_with_cond , axis=1).fillna(1)
```

or using only `apply`:

```
def nan_with_cond(row):
    if ~np.isnan(row['value_j']) : return row['value_j']
    else: 
        value = df.loc[df['node_i'] == row['node_i'], 'value_j'].mean()
        if np.isnan(value) : return 1
        else : return value

df['w'] = df.apply(nan_with_cond , axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you. Please check and let me know.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'node_i':[3,3,3,0,0,1,1],
        'node_j':[4,2,5,2,3,2,8],
        'value_i':[89,89,89,45,45,109,109],
        'value_j':[33,np.nan,69,np.nan,89,np.nan,np.nan]

        })

wList = []

for index,value in enumerate(df['value_j'].values):
    curValueNode_i = df.iloc[index,0]
    if not np.isnan(value):
        wList.append(value)
    else:
        checkIfNaNReturns = len(df[(df['node_i']==curValueNode_i) & (df['value_j'].notnull())].iloc[:,3].values)
        if (checkIfNaNReturns>0):
            meanValue = np.mean(df[(df['node_i']==curValueNode_i) & (df['value_j'].notnull())].iloc[:,3].values)
            wList.append(meanValue)
        else:
            wList.append(1)

df['w'] = wList
print(df)


'''
Output of the code:

   node_i  node_j  value_i  value_j     w
0       3       4       89     33.0  33.0
1       3       2       89      NaN  51.0
2       3       5       89     69.0  69.0
3       0       2       45      NaN  89.0
4       0       3       45     89.0  89.0
5       1       2      109      NaN   1.0
6       1       8      109      NaN   1.0

'''
```

Answer (score 0):

With apply and additional statement for last row

```
def func(x):
    if len(x)==1:
        if math.isnan(x[0]):
            return 1
        else:
            return x[0]
    elif not math.isnan(x[1]):
        return x[1]
    elif len(x)==2:
        return 1
    elif math.isnan(x[0]) or math.isnan(x[2]):
        return 1
    else:
        return (x[0]+x[2])/2



df['Output']=df['value_j'].rolling(window=3, min_periods=0).apply(lambda x: func(x), raw=True).shift(-1)
df['Output'].iloc[-1]=func(list(df['value_j'].tail(2)))
```